# "Кому и кобыла невеста"

Tags: перевод

Если ли идиоматический перевод? Если нет, то как перевести точнее всего?

Comment: "Tell me, dad,"  said the  young man,  taking  a  puff,  "are there any
marriageable young girls in this town? "
The old caretaker did not show the least surprise.
"For  some a mare'd be a  bride," he  answered, readily  striking up  a
conversation.
"I  have  no  more questions,"  said  the  young  man  quickly. http://lib.ru/ILFPETROV/ilf_petrov_12_chairs_engl.txt зря вы вопрос on-hold поставили, тут нужно знание обоих языков в равной степени, а не только английского.

Comment: кому и кобыла невеста
Set phrase: beauty is in the eye of the beholder

Универсальный русско-английский словарь. Академик.ру. 2011.

Comment: @romaklimenko Поиск идиоматического перевода на английский - чистейший оффтопик.